# Optimizing the equality and inequality operators

Tags: algorithm, caching, equality, equation-solving, union-find

I have some structures that are very expensive to compare. (They are actually trees with distinct branches.) Computing hash values for them is also expensive.

I want to create a decorator for the **eq** operator that will cache some results to speed things up. This is somewhat similar to memoization.

In particular, I want something like this to happen. Suppose we have 3 objects: A, B and C.
We compare A with B. The **eq** operator gets called, returns True, the result gets stored. We compare B with C. The **eq** operator gets called as before. Now we compare A with C. Now the algorithm should detect that A is equal to B and B is equal to C, so it should return that A is equal to C without invoking the costly **eq** operator.

I wanted to use the union-find algorithm, but it only allows for caching **equalities**, and doesn't allow to cache **inequalities**.

Suppose that we have 2 objects equal to each other: A and B. Suppose also that we have another pair of equal objects: C and D. The union-find algorithm will correctly group them into two categories (A, B) and (C, D). Now suppose A **is not** equal to C. My algorithm should cache it somehow and prevent the **eq** operator further from running on pairs (A, C), (B, C), (A, D), (B, D), since we can deduce all these pairs are unequal. Union-find does not allow that. It only saves the positive equalities, failing miserably when we have to compare many unequal objects.

My current solution is something like that:

```
def optimize(original_eq):
    def optimized_eq(first, second):
        if first is second: return True
        if hash(first) != hash(second): return False
        if cache.find(first) == cache.find(second): return True
        result = original_eq(first, second)
        if result:
            cache.union(first, second)
        else:
            pass # no idea how to save the negative result
        return result
    return optimized_eq
```

This solution would be OK if the hash function was easy to compute, but it isn't. We would be invoking cache.find on objects that are highly likely to be equal, so we would rarely need to call the original equality operator. But, as I said, the hash function is very slow on my trees (it basically needs to traverse all the tree, comparing branches on each node to remove duplicates), so I want to remove it. I want to cache the negative results instead.

Does anyone know a good solution to this problem? I need to cache not only the positive comparison results, but also negative ones.

UPDATE:

My current solutions that works for me follows:

```
def memoize_hash_and_eq(cls):
    "This decorator should be applied to the class."

    def union(key1, key2):
        nonlocal union_find
        if key1 is not key2:
            key1_leader = union_find(key1)
            key2_leader = union_find(key2)
            key1_leader._memoize_hash_and_eq__leader = key2_leader
            try:
                key2_leader._memoize_hash_and_eq__splits = key1_leader._memoize_hash_and_eq__splits
                del key1_leader._memoize_hash_and_eq__splits
            except AttributeError:
                pass

    def union_find(key):
        leader = key
        while True:
            try:
                leader = leader._memoize_hash_and_eq__leader
            except AttributeError:
                break
        if leader is not key:
            key._memoize_hash_and_eq__leader = leader
            try:
                leader.__splits = key._memoize_hash_and_eq__splits
                del key._memoize_hash_and_eq__splits
            except AttributeError:
                pass
        return leader

    def split(key1, key2):
        nonlocal union_find
        key1_leader = union_find(key1)
        key2_leader = union_find(key2)
        try:
            key1_leader._memoize_hash_and_eq__splits.add(key2_leader)
        except AttributeError:
            try:
                key2_leader._memoize_hash_and_eq__splits.add(key1_leader)
            except AttributeError:
                try:
                    key1_leader._memoize_hash_and_eq__splits = set()
                    key1_leader._memoize_hash_and_eq__splits.add(key2_leader)
                except (AttributeError, TypeError):
                    pass

    def split_find(key1, key2):
        nonlocal union_find

        key1_leader = union_find(key1)
        key2_leader = union_find(key2)

        try:
            split_leaders = key2_leader._memoize_hash_and_eq__splits
            for k in [_k for _k in split_leaders]:
                split_leaders.add(union_find(k))
            if key1_leader in split_leaders:
                return True
        except (AttributeError, TypeError):
            pass

        try:
            split_leaders = key1_leader._memoize_hash_and_eq__splits
            for k in [_k for _k in split_leaders]:
                split_leaders.add(union_find(k))
            if key2_leader in split_leaders:
                return True
        except (AttributeError, TypeError):
            pass

        return False

    def memoized_hash(self):
        return original_hash(union_find(self))
    original_hash = cls.__hash__
    cls.__hash__ = memoized_hash

    def memoized_equivalence(self, other):
        if self is other:
            return True

        if union_find(self) is union_find(other):
            return True

        if split_find(self, other):
            return False

        result = original_equivalence(self, other)
        if result is NotImplemented:
            return result
        elif result:
            union(self, other)
        else:
            split(self, other)

        return result
    original_equivalence = cls.__eq__
    cls.__eq__ = memoized_equivalence

    return cls
```

This speeds up both eq and hash.

Comment: @haeel u donot even need the not_eq operator as if two element are not of same set then any ways they are not_eq so any pairs query needs on average O(log*n). I donot think there is faster way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a very pretty solution, but how about you store, for every leader of an equivalence class (ie a root in the Union Find structure), a binary search tree containing at least(see below) all the leaders that it is *definitely unequal* to.

To query `x ?= y`: as usual, you'd find the leaders of both of them and see if they're equal. If they're not equal, find one of the leaders in the BST of the other. If present, `x` and `y` are definitely unequal.

To union two equivalence classes `x` and `y`: merge the BSTs of their leaders and set that as the BST of the new leader of the union of `x` and `y`. Nodes that enter one of the BSTs and later become non-leader are never removed from the BSTs, but that's not a huge problem - it won't cause any queries to return the wrong result, it just wastes some space (but never a lot).

Comment: This actually uses a lot of memory. It may take O(n^2) entries in the worst case. This is very close to memoizing pairs of entries for the inequality operator.

Comment: @haael yes, but typically much better.

Comment: OK, I used something close to your solution.

Comment: @haael out of curiousity, what did you do exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple union trees that are 'not equal' to each other.

For example if you find A == B, then A and B form a union-find tree.

Now you come across C. It is not in the existing union-find tree. So check it's hash with any of the elements in the tree. If C != A, then form another union-find tree that has only element C in it.

So if two elements are in different union-find trees, they are unequal and the eq function need not be called.

Comment: Unfortunately, sometimes there might be different trees for elements that are actually equal, just not compared yet. Union-find algorithm doesn't distinguish elements that are unequal from elements that have never been compared. I.e. compare A==B and then C==D. Now we have 2 different threes, despite A and C might be equal.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `O(k*n*eq_operation)` algorithm where k is number of sets. Starts with n sets, take a element v and compare with others using eq operator. If an element u not equal add item to new set else find union of v and u and continue till end of list. Do the same on new list till only one element is left.

Pseudo Code:-

```
set = all n
for i in set
parent[i] = i;

while set is not empty {

    i = set[0];
    newset = [];
    for j = 1 to set.size() {

        if(eq(i,set[j])) {

             parent[set[j]] = i;
        }         

        else {
               newset.add(set[j])
        }
    }

   set = newset

}
```

**Note:-** If no of sets is high then as good as brute force `O(n^2*eq_operation)` whereas if no of sets is low then `O(n*eq_operation)`

After this you can simply check if `parent[i] ! = parent[j]` to get inequality and `parent[i ] == parent[j]` for equality in `O(1)`.

Comment: I will analyse your solution.